# mod_wsgi "Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed" on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Python 3.6 platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, mod-wsgi, elastic-beanstalk

On AWS Elastic Beanstalk, on the "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v2.6.0 running Python 3.6" platform, there seems to be a problem with the `mod_wsgi` configuration. I see this in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf`:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
  python-home=/opt/python/run/venv/ \
  python-path=/opt/python/current/app:/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages user=wsgi group=wsgi \
  home=/opt/python/current/app
```

However, I get this in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
[Mon Nov 20 19:54:44.565076 2017] [:error] [pid 32080] mod_wsgi (pid=32080): Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed for '(null)', stopping.
[Mon Nov 20 19:54:44.565444 2017] [:error] [pid 32080] mod_wsgi (pid=32080): Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed for '/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages'.
```

Trying to access the site results in this error:

```
[Mon Nov 20 21:21:21.304605 2017] [:error] [pid 2886] [remote 71.236.217.102:39802] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myappname'
```

If I change the `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive to the following (thus removing the colon-separated paths):

```
WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
  python-home=/opt/python/run/venv/ \
  python-path=/opt/python/current/app user=wsgi group=wsgi \
  home=/opt/python/current/app
```

Then I no longer get the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

This appears to be the same bug outlined in https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/92 which was fixed in `mod_wsgi` 4.4.15. However, the AMI comes pre-installed w/ `mod24_wsgi-python36.x86_64==3.5-1.24.amzn1`.

If I try to fix the `WSGIDaemonProces`s using an .ebextensions script, it's unfixed by one of the baked-in deploy hooks, and anyway, the defaults as baked appear to be broken by default. How in the world do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered the same problem today ("64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v2.6.0 running Python 3.6", mod_wsgi errors).

I have a workaround, though I'm not sure it is a proper or the most direct solution.

#### In short

Install the latest `mod_wsgi`.

Longer explanation...

#### Check it works manually

First I did the following manually to check it works, then I scripted it so it wouldn't be destroyed on a later deploy.

Installing `mod_wsgi` will need `apxs`, so go to the instance and find packages:

```
eb ssh
yum provides apxs
```

In my case there were 3. The oldest worked on the ssh console, so I added to `.ebextensions/01_packages.config`:

```
packages:
  yum:
    ...
    httpd24-devel-2.4.27-3.75.amzn1.x86_64: []
```

Then in ssh I followed this sequence to test the manually built version od `mod_wsgi` (I couldn't get any `yum` package to work - though it can probably be done).

```
sudo -s  # become root
cd /tmp
wget -q "https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.4.21.tar.gz"
tar -xzf '4.4.21.tar.gz'
cd ./mod_wsgi-4.4.21
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.6
make
make install
```

Assuming all is good so far, restart Apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

Then look in `var/log/httpd/error_log` and hopefully you'll see:

```
... [pid 2088] AH00163: Apache/2.4.27 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/4.4.21 Python/3.6.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I reloaded the Python app page and it's working (well it had a different error but `mod_wsgi` is working).

Now to make this part of the deployment.

#### Scripting

After a few iterations, I settled on this in the `.ebextensions/...` file:

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    gcc-c++: []
    httpd24-devel-2.4.27-3.75.amzn1.x86_64: []

files:
  "/tmp/update-wsgi.sh" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # update mod_wsgi
      cd /tmp
      wget -q "https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.4.21.tar.gz" && \
      tar -xzf '4.4.21.tar.gz' && \
      cd ./mod_wsgi-4.4.21 && \
      sudo ./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.6 && \
      sudo make && \
      sudo make install && \
      sudo service httpd restart

commands:
  mod_wsgi_update:
    command: /tmp/update-wsgi.sh
    cwd: /tmp
```

Some notes:

- the `gcc` dependency is needed for `mod_wsgi` to build
- the `httpd24-devel` dependency is for the `apsx` tool