# Getting Mod_WSGI Error: Deploying Flask Application to ElasticBeanstlk

Tags: amazon-web-services, mod-wsgi, elastic-beanstalk, flask

I am current trying to deploy a Flask Application (an API Application) onto Elastic Beanstalk. But I am getting mod_wsgi error.

Here is the error message:

> [Fri Jun 01 06:10:49.314023 2018] [:warn] [pid 2801] mod_wsgi:
>   Compiled for Python/3.6.2. 
>  [Fri Jun 01 06:10:49.314039 2018]
>   [:warn] [pid 2801] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.5. 
>  [Fri
>   Jun 01 06:10:49.325648 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2801] AH00163:
>   Apache/2.4.33 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.5 configured --
>   resuming normal operations 
>  [Fri Jun 01 06:10:49.325715 2018]
>   [core:notice] [pid 2801] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D
>   FOREGROUND'
>  [Fri Jun 01 06:10:49.409813 2018] [:error] [pid 2806]
>   mod_wsgi (pid=2806): Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed for '(null)',
>   stopping. 
>  [Fri Jun 01 06:10:49.409893 2018] [:error] [pid 2806]
>   mod_wsgi (pid=2806): Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed for
>   '/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages'.
>   
>  [Fri Jun 01 06:10:52.417385 2018] [:error] [pid 2806] mod_wsgi
>   (pid=2806): Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed for '(null)', stopping.
>   
>  [Fri Jun 01 06:10:52.417463 2018] [:error] [pid 2806] mod_wsgi
>   (pid=2806): Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed for
>   '/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages'.

I have tried creating a .ebextension/package.config file and followed the instructions as shown in this link. (
Link: [mod_wsgi "Call to 'site.addsitedir()' failed" on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Python 3.6 platform](https://serverfault.com/questions/884469/mod-wsgi-call-to-site-addsitedir-failed-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-python-3?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) It seems like the environment is not actually invoking the commands in the .ebextension.

Here is how I uploaded my files and deployed it onto AWS.

- I compressed the files using the right click function on my mac
- List item I used the AWS EB Console to upload and deploy the zip file

Am I missing something in this process?

Even after i relaunched the environment and restarted the server, I still get this error.

Can anyone help please, thank you!